# SQL - store Function output for multiple uses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm performing a function multiple times within my Select statement:

```
Select Substring(AccNo,5,3),

Case When Substring(AccNo,5,3)='ABC' then
   ABC'
Else
   'Other'
End as AType

Case When Substring(AccNo,5,3)='DEF' then
   'DEF'
Else
   'Other'
End as Btype   

From MainTable
```

In reality, my code does about 20 different operations on the same Function output and it is more complicated than this example - but the principle stands.

In most languages, I would just perform the Function ONCE and store the result in a variable, to save unnecessary processing. I'm having trouble finding how I would do something like that in SQL - or do I assume that SQL Server is very smart and knows it only has to perform the function once and store the result?

```
Set Result=Substring(AccNo,5,3)

Case When Result='ABC'
etc
```

Comment: I see no where in your example where you are calling a function, unless you are refering to `Substring()`

Comment: You mean that you want to get ride from `SUBSTRING()` function?

Comment: Yes - Substring is the function I mean in this example.

Comment: @Sami What do you mean by "get ride from SUBSTRING"?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Res = 'ABC' THEN 'ABC' ELSE 'Other' END AType,
       CASE WHEN Res = 'DEF' THEN 'DEF' ELSE 'Other' END BType
FROM
(
SELECT Substring(AccNo,5,3) Res --You write SUBSTRING() just one time
From MainTable
) T
```

Comment: This won't work because it doesn't fit with the main structure of the query. Nice idea though, thank you.

Comment: @Lefty Really? How?

Comment: What does "fit the structure" mean? This approach seems to do exactly what you wanted.

Comment: @SMor Maybe cause the answer owner is "Sami" thus it won't work

Comment: You're right, sorry. My input is a huge JOIN with hundreds of fields - that was the source of my concern - but actually I think it might be irrelevant, I can just use this approach anyway. It will mean quite a bit of change to my existing code but it may well be the answer.

Comment: A subquery does not guarantee that the function is called only once.  Check this out:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b77691e388a0cdea3c281eb2c5aaf9c7.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In my answer I comment "Write" not "run"

Comment: My main problem is that the size of the input tables might cause this to be very slow. I hope not. When I get a chance to investigate, I will report back and mark this as the answer if it runs in a reasonable time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible within a single query.  I had thought `apply` would do the trick:

```
Select str,
       (Case When str = 'ABC' then 'ABC' Else 'Other'
        End) as AType,
       (Case When str = 'DEF' then 'DEF' Else 'Other'
        End) as BType
From MainTable mt cross apply
     (values (Substring(AccNo, 5, 3)) v(str);
```

But it doesn't.  Subqueries and CTEs also have no guarantee that the function is called only once per row.

EDIT:

I'm leaving the answer, but there is no guarantee.  SQL Server reserves the right to rearrange operations, so even this:

```
select *
from (values (1), (2), (3)) v(x) cross apply
     (select newid() as y) y
```

Calls `newid()` three times.  See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=91537c688428607b7b186b5aebb69a2f).

Comment: This is a workable way of achieving it I think. I will have to do some experimentation. Thank you.

Comment: It's not just workable, it's the standard way of factoring expressions in a query.  Whether they call functions or not.  Of course, the cross apply expression is processed once per row. that's just how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your expected output, but if you need to have a column for each `SUBSTRING(AccNo,5,3)` type. It's possible by using `PIVOT` here is a quick example :

```
DECLARE 
    @t TABLE (AccNo VARCHAR(50), AccName VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('8001ABC0011047', 'Personal'),
('3022DEF9028683', 'Internal'),
('6709GHI90217096', 'Local'),
('2014JKL17800222', 'International')

SELECT 
    AccNo
,   ABC AType 
,   DEF BType 
,   GHI CType
FROM (
    SELECT *, SUBSTRING(AccNo,5,3) AccountType
    FROM @t
) D
PIVOT(
    MAX(AccountType) 
    FOR AccountType IN(ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL)
) PV
```

If you're using it too often in other queries, you can use a scalar function, something like :

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetAccountType
(
    @AccNo  VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN 
    CASE SUBSTRING(@AccNo,5,3) 
        WHEN 'ABC' THEN 'ABC'
        WHEN 'DEF' THEN 'DEF'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END 

END
```

And then you call it like this :

```
SELECT dbo.GetAccountType(AccNo) AccountType 
FROM @t
```

This would be a more code reuse approach.

Comment: I've never come across "Pivot" before so I'm struggling to understand this - but I will persevere and see if it provides a workable solution. In reality, where I've used "Substring" in my example is actually a UDF which is pretty complicated and I've already seen what a speed impact it can have when just running once per Row. If I have to run it 20 times per Row it will likely have a catastrophic effect on the run time. Hence my desire to store its output and re-use it.

Comment: @Lefty, if you are going to reuse the output, I would recommend setting it up, then create a view of it. This way you can reuse it anywhere you want without the need of replicating the whole code.

Comment: A View was the way forward! I just created a view with all the fields in the table, then an  extra column with the output of the function. If anything, it seems actually FASTER than reading the table directly and calling the function once! Thank you!